# Java Queue, Dequeue and Printing All Values Within The Queued/Dequeued List

Tags: java, linked-list

Hello I think I'm really having a hard time with this part. I'm making a program that accepts a value from the user a first name and last name, and then Queues it (CASE1).  Then is able to dequeue it (CASE2) and finally show everything on the list. There are no errors on the IDE, but I cant get the result that I want, At CASE 2 it throws the exception error, means that the list that gets passed to it is empty. At CASE 3 no values are shown. How do I fix this?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Iterator;

class Customer2 {
    public String lastName;
    public String firstName;
    public Customer2() {
    }
    public Customer2(String last, String first) {
       this.lastName = last;
       this.firstName = first;
    }
    public String toString() {
       return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
 }
class HourlyCustomer2 extends Customer2 {
    public double hourlyRate;
    public HourlyCustomer2(String last, String first) {
       super(last, first);
    }
 }



class Queue1<E> {

    private LinkedList<E> list = new LinkedList<E>();

    public void enqueue(E item) {
        list.addLast(item);
    }

    public E dequeue() {

        // return a Customer2 with null values if empty? (up to you)

            return list.remove(0);
    }

    public E isNotEnd(){

        return list.getLast();
    }

    public boolean hasItems() {

        return !list.isEmpty();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {

        return list.isEmpty();
    }

    public Iterator<E> iterator() {

        return list.iterator();
    }

    public E removeFirst() {

        return list.removeFirst();
    }

    public E getFirst() {

        return list.getFirst();
    }

    public int size() {

        return list.size();
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {

        return false;
    }

    public void addItems(Queue1<? extends E> q) {

        while (q.hasNext()) list.addLast(q.dequeue());
    }
}


public class something {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input1;
        String input2;
        int choice = 1000;

        Queue1<Customer2> empList;
        empList = new Queue1<Customer2>();
        Queue1<HourlyCustomer2> hList;
        hList = new Queue1<HourlyCustomer2>();

        do {

            System.out.println("================");
            System.out.println("Queue Operations Menu");
            System.out.println("================");
            System.out.println("1,Enquene");
            System.out.println("2,Dequeue");
            System.out.println("3,View queue");
            System.out.println("0, Quit\n");
            System.out.println("Enter Choice:");

            try {

                choice = sc.nextInt();

                switch(choice) {

                    case 1:

                        System.out.println("\nPlease enter last name:  ");
                        input1 = sc.next();
                        System.out.println("\nPlease enter first name:  ");
                        input2 = sc.next();
                        hList.enqueue(new HourlyCustomer2(input1, input2));
                        empList.addItems(hList);

                        System.out.println("\n"+(input2 + " " +  input1) + " is successful queued");

                        break;

                    case 2:

                        if (empList.isEmpty()) {
                            System.out.println("The queue is empty!");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        System.out.println("\nDequeued customer: "  +empList.getFirst());
                        empList.removeFirst();
                        }


                        System.out.println("\nNext customer in queue: "  +empList.getFirst()+"\n");

                        break;

                    case 3:

                        System.out.println("\nThe Customer's names are: \n");

                        Iterator<Customer2> it = empList.iterator();

                        while (it.hasNext()) {

                              System.out.println("\nThe customers' names are: \n");
                        }

                        break;

                    case 0:

                        System.exit(0);

                    default:

                        System.out.println("Invalid choice");
                }
            }
            catch(InputMismatchException e) {

                System.out.println("Please enter 1-5, 0 to quit");
                sc.nextLine();
            }

        } while(choice != 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your custom queue; you forgot to put the logic in your hasNext method. It will always return false. Therefore your addItems loop will never add any items to the queue.

If you need a hint towards how to do the hasNext(), my recommendation is to look at the size of your list and make a simple comparison.

```java
public boolean hasNext() {

    return false;
}

public void addItems(Queue1<? extends E> q) {

    while (q.hasNext()) list.addLast(q.dequeue());
}
```

PS: I noticed that your code also shows the next in line. You might want to check if it's empty or hasNext() before that to not get a crash if the list was empty after that dequeuing.

Comment: what do you think should I put in my hasNext() method?